# Comparing binomial dependent variables?

Tags: r, binary-data

I have 4 tests that use different procedures to detect bacteria. I want to compare the detection rates by the test used. My data is arranged such that I have each test in a column and their detection per sample as 1s or 0s e.g.

```r
PCR  Gramstain  tissue
0       0         1
1       1         0
1       1         1
1       0         0
0       0         0
```

I can also stack the data like so:

```r
values   Ind
0        PCR
0        Gramstain
1        tissue
1        PCR
1        Gramstain
0        tissue
```

my issue is that I'm having trouble conceptualizing the way to make this comparison. Should I use a binomial regression with each test as a separate independent variable? should I use a chi squared contingency table?

Comment: This is much more statistics than programming, so it will probably get migrated to stats.stackexchange, but I'd suggest having a look a `?prop.test`.

Comment: How many observations do you have? It seems the tests are used for the same bacteria, you could also be interested in presenting (pairwise) contingency tables, and look not only at the detection rates, but at the agreement: [tag:agreement-statistics]